# Why isn't the coroutine state deallocated?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-coroutine

I'm trying to understand how the C++ coroutines work, but it's not clear to me why the coroutine state is never deallocated as the loop progresses.

I'd expect the promise created by `second(loop)` to be destroyed right after the `co_await` expression returns, since it's not stored anywhere. What am I missing?

```
#include <uv.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <experimental/coroutine>

class service {
public:
    struct awaiter;
    struct promise_type;

    using coro_handle = std::experimental::coroutine_handle<promise_type>;

    coro_handle _co;

    service(coro_handle co) : _co(co) {
    }

    service(const service &) = delete;
    service(service &&) = delete;

    awaiter operator co_await();
};

struct final_awaitable {
    std::experimental::coroutine_handle<> _co;

    final_awaitable(std::experimental::coroutine_handle<> co) : _co(co) {
    }

    bool await_ready() noexcept {
        return false;
    }

    std::experimental::coroutine_handle<> await_suspend(std::experimental::coroutine_handle<>) noexcept {
        if (_co) {
            return _co;
        } else {
            return std::experimental::noop_coroutine();
        }
    }

    void await_resume() noexcept {}
};

template<typename T>
concept UvRunnable = requires(T) {
  { &T::uv_run_task };
};

struct sleep {
    unsigned long _delay;

    explicit sleep(unsigned long delay) : _delay(delay) {
    }

    auto uv_run_task(uv_loop_t* loop, void* co) {
        uv_timer_t *timer = new uv_timer_t{};
        uv_timer_init(loop, timer);
        timer->data = co;
        uv_timer_start(timer, &on_sleep_done, _delay, 0);
        return std::experimental::suspend_always{};
    }

    static void on_sleep_done(uv_timer_t *timer) {
        auto co = std::experimental::coroutine_handle<>::from_address(timer->data);
        delete timer;
        co.resume();
    }
};

struct service::promise_type {
    uv_loop_t* _loop;
    std::experimental::coroutine_handle<> _continuation;

    promise_type(uv_loop_t *loop) : _loop(loop) {}

    auto get_return_object() {
        return service::coro_handle::from_promise(*this);
    }

    auto initial_suspend() {
        return std::experimental::suspend_never();
    }

    auto final_suspend() noexcept {
        return final_awaitable{ _continuation };
    }

    void return_void() {
    }

    void* operator new(std::size_t n) {
        std::cout << "Allocating " << n << " bytes" << std::endl;
        return ::operator new(n);
    }

    void operator delete(void* ptr, std::size_t size) {
        std::cout << "Freeing memory" << std::endl;
        ::operator delete(ptr);
    }

    template <typename T>
    auto && await_transform(T &&obj) const noexcept {
        return std::forward<T>(obj);
    }

    template <UvRunnable T>
    auto await_transform(T cmd) {
        return cmd.uv_run_task(_loop, coro_handle::from_promise(*this).address());
    }

    void unhandled_exception() {
        std::cout << "Unhandled exception" << std::endl;
        std::terminate();
    }
};

struct service::awaiter {
    service::coro_handle _co;

    awaiter(coro_handle co) : _co(co) {
    }

    bool await_ready() {
        return false;
    }

    void await_suspend(std::experimental::coroutine_handle<> co_cont) {
        _co.promise()._continuation = co_cont;
    }

    void await_resume() {
    }
};

service::awaiter service::operator co_await() {
    return service::awaiter(_co);
}

service second(uv_loop_t *loop) {
    co_await sleep(1);
}

service service_main(uv_loop_t *loop) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        std::cout << "#" << i << std::endl;
        co_await second(loop);
    }
}

int main() {
    uv_loop_t loop;
    uv_loop_init(&loop);

    std::cout << "before service_main" << std::endl;
    service_main(&loop);
    std::cout << "after service_main" << std::endl;
    int res = uv_run(&loop, UV_RUN_DEFAULT);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It'd be helpful to provide a [mcve] - in this case something that doesn't depend on `uv`. Also if you could use C++20 too (e.g. `<coroutine>`, not `<experimental/coroutine>`, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Returning a suspended awaitable in `final_suspend` prevents the promise from being automatically collected after returning, requiring to call `destroy` to delete it.

To fix my code, I needed to instead queue the `_continuation.resume()` call somewhere, and make `final_suspend` return `std::suspend_never`.